# Eigenvalues and their algebraic multiplicities for a sum of two commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, triangulation

Question:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two real $n×n$ matrices which commute and let $a_1, a_2,..., a_n$ (not necessarily distinct) be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $b_1 ,...,b_n$ are eigenvalues (not necessarily distinct) of $B$.
>
> (1) Are $a_1 + b_1,...,a_n +b_n$ the eigenvalues of $A+B$ ?
>
> (2) If $a$ is eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$ and $b$
> is eigenvalue of $B$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$, then is $a+b$ an eigenvalue of $A+B$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$ ?

My attempt: I know that if $A$ & $B$ are commutating real matrices then they are simultaneously triangularizable  & from this we can get, spectrum of $A+ B$ is **contained** in $\{a_1 + b_1 : a_1 ∈ σ(A)  , b_1 ∈ σ(B) \}$
But then how can we get (1) and (2) from this?

Answer (score 2):

Just consider $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&-1}$ and the following two different cases: $B=A$ and $B=\pmatrix{-1&0\\ 0&1}$.

Comment: So is that mean answer to about two questions is false? If so please can u tell me, when those are true? Is there is any condition?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes, both are false.

Comment: So when they are true? if i consider $I$ as $101× 101$ identity matrix and J as $101× 101$ matrix with each entries $1$ then, eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$ with $A.M = 101$ and eigenvalues of $J $are $0 $with $A.M = 100$ and $1$with A.M = 1. Clearly $101- 1 = 100$ is eigenvalue of $J-I$ and $ 0-1 = -1 $ is eigenvalue of $J-I$. So in this case (1) is true. Why so? Is there is any reason?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi If two matrices commute, they can be simultaneously triangularised over $\mathbb C$. So, if $a_i$ denotes the $i$-th diagonal entry in the aforementioned triangulation and similarly for $b_i$), then the eigenvalues of $A+B$ are indeed $a_i+b_i$. But (1) is not true in general because the order of eigenvalues is unspecified. Unless all eigenvalues in one matrix are identical, you can always scramble the eigenvalues to make (1) or (2) false. Your example works because all eignevalues of $A$ are equal to each other.

Comment: Thank u so much get it. :-) so we can say (1) is true when all eigenvalues of  $A$ or  $B$ or of $A$ & $B$ are same?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Yes, but note that if all eigenvalues of $A$ are the same, we must have $k=n$. In turn, the statement of (2) becomes "if all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $a$ **and** all eigenvalues of $B$ are equal to some $b$, then all eigenvalues of $A+B$ are equal to $a+b$".